# Is there a program that can select the smallest files by size during a file conflict in windows 10

Tags: windows-explorer, filenames, jpeg, png, steam

So I'm resizing some VTFs by converting them back into PNGs then sizing them down to 512x512 as maximum anything smaller stays what it is. that said I have 2 folders 1.oldmats 2.newmats. now while doing this i noticed sometimes after the conversion some of the originals are smaller than the new mats (This is cause they were jpgs before getting converted and their dimensions didn't get changed.)

Overall my question is if I wanted to combine the folders, but wanted to select the smallest sized file from each one for each file name conflict what is the best way to automate this? I'm dealing with a large number of files (2000+) for each set of materials. and don't feel like manually doing this each time for each one.

I could just convert them to jpg and hope none of in-game models need the transparency data. but that's not what my question is for since this would be useful to know/learn.

Comment: If you have two folder you are comparing, you could write a PowerShell script that goes through each file in the course folder and check if the same filename exists in the second folder, and if so, compare file sizes and then delete the larger image.

Comment: Free File Sync can do this too. You basically merge both folders, and before you start the copy, you let it check what will happen. You can set how it handle conflicts or just manually go through them.